# Is there a reason we can't populate types with DataKinds?

Tags: haskell, data-kinds

With DataKinds, a definition like

```
data KFoo = TFoo
```

introduces the kind `KFoo :: BOX` and the type `TFoo :: KFoo`. Why can't I then go on to define

```
data TFoo = CFoo
```

such that `CFoo :: TFoo`, `TFoo :: KFoo`, `KFoo :: BOX`?

Do all constructors need to belong to a type that belongs to the kind `*`? If so, why?

**Edit**: I don't get an error when I do this, because constructors and types share a namespace, but GHC permits conflicts because it disambiguates names as regular types, rather than promoted constructors. The docs say to prefix with a `'` to refer to the promoted constructor. When I change that second line to

```
data 'TFoo = CFoo
```

I get the error

> Malformed head of type or class declaration: TFoo

Comment: What error do you get when you try to define `data TFoo`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Do all constructors need to belong to a type that belongs to the kind `*`?

Yes. That's exactly what `*` means: it's the kind of (lifted / boxed, I'm never sure about that part) Haskell types. Indeed all other kinds aren't really kinds of types though they share the `type` syntax. Rather `*` is the metatype-level type for types, and all other kinds are metatype-level types for things that aren't types but type constructors or something completely different.

(Again, there's also something about unboxed-type kinds; those certainly are types but I think this isn't possible for a `data` constructor.)

Comment: Typically I wouldn't type the word "type" so often in a single post.

Comment: `*` is kind of all lifted types and `#` is unlifted. `*` and `#` together  encapsulate all types which have values. Boxed just refers to if something is a pointer or not, I believe.

Comment: Boxed, unboxed types have the kind `#` which is why you can't use them in polymorphic functions, kind mismatched. There's also `?` which is the top of all kinds and `??` which is the lub of `*` and `#`.

Answer (score 6):

> Do all constructors need to belong to a type that belongs to the kind *? If so, why?

The most important reason why they must be of type `*` (or `#`) is the phase separation employed by GHC: `DataKinds` get erased during compilation. We can represent them runtime only indirectly, by defining singleton GADT datatypes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

data Nat = Z | S Nat

data SNat n where
   SZ :: SNat Z
   SS :: SNat n -> SNat (S n)
```

But the `DataKind` indices themselves still don't exist runtime. The various kinds offer a simple rule for phase separation, which wouldn't be as straightforward with dependent types (even though it would potentially simplify type level programming greatly).